# Error calling unzip with system.process.start()

Tags: c#

Having a weird problem. I have this C# snippet of code I am using to a extract self-extracting .exe on a CentOS 6.5 machine with Mono:

```
try
                {
                    //new bash process
                    Process bash = new Process();

                    bash.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/bash";
                    string command = @"unzip " + Globals.fiberDirectory + @"""" + file + ".exe" + @"""";
                    //Check command string
                    Console.WriteLine(command);
                    bash.StartInfo.Arguments = "-c \" " + command + " \"";
                    bash.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    bash.Start();


                }


            catch (Exception e)
            {


                Console.WriteLine("    ...Not Loaded! - " + e.Message);


            }
            finally
            {
            }
```

It outputs this:

```
unzip "/home/pan/maps/data/telus/FVData/Fiber/5656 all.exe"


unzip:  cannot find or open /home/pan/maps/data/telus/FVData/Fiber/5656, /home/pan/maps/data/telus/FVData/Fiber/5656.zip or /home/pan/maps/data/telus/FVData/Fiber/5656.ZIP.
```

when I run this command from my shell manually:

```
unzip /home/pan/maps/data/telus/FVData/Fiber/"5656 all.exe"
```

It works perfectly. Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried using the process `cmd` and making the arguments `unzip [insert filename here]`

Comment: Why involve `bash` at all? Why not `/usr/bin/unzip` (or the similar path on your system) as the `StartInfo.FileName`?